# Passing array to a routine going wrong

Tags: perl

In the following code I am expecting output in ScheduleRequestWrite() to be : 5,10

```
sub ProcessItem
{
    my @writeVal = ("5,10");

    foreach my $str (@writeVal)
    {
        print "\nProcessItem = $str\n";
    }
    ScheduleRequestWrite(\@writeVal);
}

sub ScheduleRequestWrite()
{
   my @write_value = $_[0];

   foreach my $str (@write_value)
   {
        print "\n$str\n";
   }
}

ProcessItem();
```

But I am getting : ARRAY<0x2ccf8>

Could anyone please help me point out my mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are passing an array reference, not an array.

Comment: Since you  are passing an array reference, you should dereference `$_[0]` in `ScheduleRequestWrite()` : `my @write_value = @$_[0]`

Comment: @HåkonHægland that's wrong.  `@{$_[0]}`.  What you wrote dereferences `$_` and gets a slice of the 0th index in the referred array.  But better to just have the variable contain a reference, as in the given answer.

Comment: @ysth Thanks, you are completely right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing in an array reference, `\@writeVal`, and then using that reference in your array `@write_value` ... so your array `@write_value` has a single item in it, a reference to another array.

You may have meant `my @write_value = @{$_[0]};` which makes a copy of the array, or you may have meant to loop over the original array directly:

```
sub ScheduleRequestWrite
{
   my $write_value = $_[0];

   foreach my $str (@$write_value)
   {
        print "\n$str\n";
   }
}
```

(You also don't want the `()` prototype since you *are* taking a parameter! Just leave the prototype off.)